# UItableView with multiple section Expand/Collapse keeping few cell always visible

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a  UITableView with expand/collapse option when user tap a button on footer but I don’t want the table to collapse all the way, I want few cell to stay always visible and expand from that point and collapse till that point . My table view has three sections and the number of visible cell for each section can be different. I was able to expand and collapse it all the way when custom footer button is clicked but struggling to keep different number of visible cell for different section. (I am using NIB and also new in Objective-C)
Thanks in advance, for any further clarification please let me know.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FOOTER";
    CustomFootrCell *customFooter=[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
//Section shoud be 'section'
    [customFooter.expandButton setTag:section];
    [customFooter.expandButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(expandButton:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return customFooter;
}

-(void)expandButton: (id)sender{
    //Here all my conditons to decide if that section is expanded/collapsed
    //And update it accordingly on numberOfRowsInSection method
//Add begin and end for animation
     [self.myTablebeginUpdates];

    [self.myTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[sender tag]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 [self.myTableendUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, I need to see how you are setting the condition inside expandButton when it’s clicked. You can set how many row should be visible for each section on your `numberOfRowsInSection`
Like this

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if(section==1 ){
        if(sectionOneExpanded==true ){
            return totalNumberOfRowForThatSection_When_Expanded;
        }
        else{
            return Total_Number_Of_Row_TO_Keep_Visible_When_Collapse;
        }
    }
    else if(section==2){
        if(sectionTwoExpanded==true){
            return totalNumberOfRowForThatSection_When_Expanded;
        }
        else{
            return Total_Number_Of_Row_TO_Keep_Visible_When_Collapse;
        }
    }
    else if(section==3){
        if(sectionThreeExpanded==true){
            return totalNumberOfRowForThatSection_When_Expanded;
        }
        else{
            return Total_Number_Of_Row_TO_Keep_Visible_When_Collapse;
        }
    }
}
```

and can add action for expandButton like this

```
-(void)expandButton: (id)sender{
    //Here you can do something like that 
    if([sender tag]==1){
        //Set a falg to see if the section is already expanded or not
        SectionOneExpended=!SectionOneExpended;
    }
    else if([sender tag]==2){
        SectionTwoExpended=!SectionTwoExpended;
    }
    [self.myTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[sender tag]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

I have a simple example on git you can check [this](https://github.com/Mahbub-Ahmed/ExploreTableView/blob/master/UI/Controllers/MAHomeViewController.m)
Hope it helps....

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I am going to try it and see if it works. Your git example project is legit :)